# NextJS - ReactDOMServer does not yet support Suspense

Tags: next.js

I'm currently trying to incorporate a loader component to a site built with NextJS. I would like to use Suspense to show a loading screen may it be after refreshing the page or changing routes.
This is how my code goes:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Loader } from '../components/loader'
const { Suspense } = require('React')

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
   return (
   <>
     <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <Head>
         .... some codes such as meta tags, title tags ....
        </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
      </Suspense>
   </>
   )
}
```

My problem is I get an error that says **ReactDOMServer does not yet support Suspense.** but I would like to use Suspense to enable a loading screen on my page. Much like this [website](https://www.sunniesface.com/)

Comment: Which version of next and React are you using

Answer (score 8):

You can use React 18 features like `suspense` in Next.js [Advanced Features](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/react-18). Obviously it's still experimental and might cause issues with you application.

```
npm install next@latest react@rc react-dom@rc
```

To enable, use the experimental flag `concurrentFeatures: true`

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    concurrentFeatures: true,
  },
}
```

Once enabled, you can use Suspense and SSR streaming for all pages.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { lazy, Suspense } from 'react'

import Content from '../components/content'

// These two ways are identical:
const Profile = dynamic(() => import('./profile'), { suspense: true })
const Footer = lazy(() => import('./footer'))

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
        {/* A component that uses Suspense-based */}
        <Content />
      </Suspense>
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
        <Profile />
      </Suspense>
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
        <Footer />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I ended up simulating the `Suspense` with a combination of `setState` & `componentDidMount`

```
render(){
    return this.state.browser ? <Component/> : <Placeholder/>
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({browser: true})
}
```

I hope it helps.