# Suspense not working in NEXTJS - How to convert to i18next then?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next, react-suspense

I want to use Suspense in my nextjs project but I get such an error whenever I use it:
[image: Error]

Then I got to know that a solution does exist, the error can be rectified by modifying the ***next-i18next-config.js*** file like

```
react: {
  useSuspense: false,
  wait: true
}
```

However I only have the *next.config.js* in my project and do not know how to inculcate i18next in my existing nextjs project.
Are there any other solutions for this? If not, how can I modify my project to include i18next?

Comment: what is nextjs version that you arre using>'

Comment: @AnkushVerma 12.0.2

Comment: check this out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433673/nextjs-reactdomserver-does-not-yet-support-suspense)